# Getting some error while calling connect method for ssl wrapped socket

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate

My ssl server and client code is working fine on windows machine. However when I try to execute the same code on Ubuntu machine then I am getting some error while execution of following line code at client end:

```
sslconnection.connect((host,port))
```

All code files and certificate file exists in same folder.

```
File "clientsideCode.py", line 24, in <module>
    sslConnection.connect((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 433, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 414, in _real_connect
    self.ca_certs, self.ciphers)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:344: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

code I am using to wrap the socket with ssl:

```
sslconnection = ssl.wrap_socket(clientsocket,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,ca_certs="server.crt")
```

Comment: Is the version of Python on Ubuntu 2.7.9+ ?

Comment: Python version 2.7. I think, I have most recent version of ubuntu

Comment: What is the minor version though ? If you type Python in a console and the REPL starts up, what is the full version number. There were changes in the SSL handling in 2.7.9, and Ubuntu doesn't always let you have the latest version ie. Ubuntu12.04 ships with Python 2.7.3 and is pegged to that.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 4.04.3 LTS from Ubuntu website.

Comment: That would likely be 2.7.6 for Ubuntu 14.04. It should also have Python 3.4 installed, and you can try running your program with python3 instead of just python

Comment: According to above error message, I am using python 2.7

Comment: The directory doesn't tell you the minor version. Checking the REPL or Python -V will though.

Comment: ssl.CERT_REQUIRED is a server side option (to request the client certificate) and should not be used at the client side. Try without.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: if this is the case then why same code is working on windows machine.  I will check on ubuntu. You are right that this option is not needed and I tried with this option on windows machine and will try on ubuntu as well.

Comment: @ChristianWitts: python version is 2.7.6

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I removed the ssl.CERT_REQUIRED and now getting following error:     sslconnection.connect((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 433, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 423, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Comment: "EOF occurred in violation of protocol" - the other side closed the connection during handshake. Maybe you tried to connect to a service which does not speak SSL at all, otherwise it might be a problem with ciphers or whatever. Have you tried with another client like a browser (if this is https)?. If you have control of the server looks there for errors.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks. There was problem with certificate or key. However, I copied again from windows machine to linux then everything worked smoothly. If you want to answer the question then let me know. Otherwise I will delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is solved now here a short write-up for anybody stumbling over this kinds of problems:

> ```
> ... ssl.wrap_socket(clientsocket,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED...
> ```

This caused the initial problem because CERT_REQUIRED is an option for the server side (to require client certificates) and will only cause problems when used wrongly on the client side.

But after this was solved another issue popped up:

> ... EOF occurred in violation of protocol

This means that the server closed the connection during the handshake. This error is commonly seen when protocols or ciphers don't match or when the server simply has the wrong setup. More information can often be gained by looking at error messages at the server side. Here it obviously was the latter case, i.e the wrong setup:

> There was problem with certificate or key. However, I copied again from windows machine to linux then everything worked smoothly.